# Malta visa VFS global "unauthorized user"

Tags: visas, vfs-global, malta

I'm trying to apply to a Schengen visa to visit Malta.

I've been directed to make an appointment on vfs.global's website. But it doesn't allow me to proceed to the final step.

Is this the correct website to apply to a Schengen visa to Malta? Does anyone know what I'm missing?

[image]

Comment: That looks like the correct site. There may be a temporary technical problem, have you tried contacting VFS https://visa.vfsglobal.com/gbr/en/mlt/contact-us?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP should contact the VFS support team for advice